# How to make Emacs byte-compilation warnings errors

Tags: testing, emacs

In my continuous integration testing for my emacs package [fsharp-mode](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/tree/master/emacs), I am adding byte-compilation to the tests, in order to have immediate feedback. I am roughly using:

```
 emasc -batch batch-byte-compile *.el
```

This returns non-zero if there is an error, but not if it is just a warning. I would like to be alerted also if there are any warnings, as this may include calls to undefined functions (which has happened before thanks to a typo).

So: how can I obtain a non-zero return code in case of compilation warnings?

Comment: Have you tried `byte-compile-error-on-warn`?

Comment: I have now, thanks. Seems obvious, but I couldn't find it in the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `byte-compile-error-on-warn` to a non-nil value, as in:

```
$ emacs -Q --batch \
    --eval '(setq byte-compile-error-on-warn t)' \
    -f batch-byte-compile *.el
```

The byte compiler now stops at the first warning, though, so you should make this setting optional in your `Makefile`, and only use it in your CI setup.

If you need more sophisticated control than that, you have to write your own post-processor, e.g. a Python script that parses the output of the byte compiler and adjusts the exit code and/or output accordingly, or write your own `batch-byte-compile` variant that does more sophisticated processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems obvious, but I couldn't find it in the manual.